# OneNote - Sorry it looks like this page was added from another computer and hasn't synced yet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I am trying to create OneNote items using Microsoft Graph.

```
/v1.0/users/{email}/onenote/pages?sectionName=MyNotes
```

Sometimes when I create a which has large amount of HTML content, it gives me an error:

> Sorry it looks like this page was added from another computer and hasn't synced yet

More details here
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles-sdweb/onenote-sorry-it-looks-like-this-page-was-added/ad53ccb6-ce85-4f89-b199-bd4c2d5a3449?tm=1515577241343

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. You're question is lacking sufficient detail to allow the community help you out. Without sample code and content the community won't be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: This seems to be a generic error when the html data is malformed but the page itself is created. I have tended to get it when creating pages with ink data or pictures. I would suggest trial and error; i.e. remove all the html data  and then add portions of it back until you get the error to determine which part of the html is malformed.